Reason for property of convex decreasing sequences of reciprocals of positive integers; property defined with greedy algorithm
Let $a_0 < a_1$ be positive integers. Define recursively the sequence $(a_n)$ so that $a_{n+1}$ is the greatest positive integer, if one exists, such that $\left( \frac{1}{a_{n-1}}, \frac{1}{a_n}, \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} \right) $ is strictly convex, that is, $ \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} > \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}. $ I would like to prove or disprove the following proposition.

Proposition: If $\ \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ a_n>0 $ exists, then
$a_{n+1}-a_n$ is constant (or eventually constant).

[In particular, I am interested if there is such a sequence $(a_n)$ satisfying the conditions such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges. But if the proposition is true, then such a sequence obviously cannot exist.]
For example, the sequence starting $\frac{1}{a_0} = \frac{1}{2},\ \frac{1}{a_1} = \frac{1}{3}, $ continues $\frac{1}{a_2} = \frac{1}{5},\ \frac{1}{a_3} = \frac{1}{14},\ $ and now $a_5$ does not exist because there is no such "greatest positive integer" satisfying the convexity condition.
The sequence starting $\frac{1}{a_0} = \frac{1}{3},\ \frac{1}{a_1} = \frac{1}{4}, $ continues $\frac{1}{a_2} = \frac{1}{5},\ \frac{1}{a_3} = \frac{1}{6},\ $ and $\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{n+3}$ for all $n.$
Two further examples with $a_1-a_0 = 3$ (in particular, they are the "borderline" examples):
The sequence starting $\frac{1}{a_0} = \frac{1}{20},\ \frac{1}{a_1} = \frac{1}{23}, $ continues $\frac{1}{a_2} = \frac{1}{27},\ \frac{1}{a_3} = \frac{1}{32},\ \frac{1}{a_4} = \frac{1}{39},\ \frac{1}{a_5} = \frac{1}{49},\ \frac{1}{a_6} = \frac{1}{65},\ \frac{1}{a_7} = \frac{1}{96},\  \frac{1}{a_8} = \frac{1}{183},\ \frac{1}{a_9} = \frac{1}{1951},\ $ and now $a_{10}$ does not exist because there is no such "greatest positive integer" satisfying the convexity condition.
However, the sequence starting $\frac{1}{a_0} = \frac{1}{21},\ \frac{1}{a_1} = \frac{1}{24}, $ continues $\frac{1}{a_2} = \frac{1}{27},\ \frac{1}{a_3} = \frac{1}{30},\ $ and $\frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{3n+21}$ for all $n.$
Note that all these sequences satisfy the proposition.
Also of interest is this entire question with $\geq$ instead of $>$ in the convexity condition.
Edit: I wonder if this  has anything to do with continued fractions.

Isn't $a_n = 2^n$ is a counterexample?

@TheoBendit No. If $a_0=1$ and $a_1= 1/2$ then $a_2$ cannot exist because there is no greatest integer $m$ such that $1/1 - 1/2 > 1/2 - 1/m$, i.e., $1/m > 1/2 - (1-1/2) = 0.$ In other words, the sequence starting with $a_0=1$ and $a_1= 1/2$ does not continue. In particular, it does not satisfy the property that $a_n>0$ for all $n$ (since $a_n$ does not even exist for $n=2$), so it cannot be a counter-example.

Probably the answer is yes, and a proof outline is like this: If $a_{n+1}\geq (a_{n}-a_{n-1}) + a_n +1,$ then [something about $a_{n+1}$ in relation to $a_n$], which implies [something about $a_{n+2}$ in relation to $a_{n+1}$], and so on. Eventually, there exists $m$ such that $a_{n+m} > 2a_{n+m-1},$ which then implies that $a_{n+m+1}<0,$ or more precisely, $a_{n+m+1}$ does not exist.

I have been thinking about the problem. It's not difficult to get a second order recurrence relation that will definitely stall if the original sequence stalls. The idea is, perhaps we can find some necessary condition for an infinite series that will seriously reduce the possibilities. The problem is, the recurrence relation is very non-linear, as is every substitution I could think of to help break it down. I can't figure out when the recurrence relation will stall, so it didn't really help.

Regarding the distinction between "constant" and "eventually constant": have you found any sequence where every term exists, and the differences are eventually constant, but not constant?

It looks like $(a_0,a_1)$ leads to an infinite sequence if and only if $2(a_1-a_0)^2\le 2a_0-a_1$.

@VarunVejalla Your condition (on $(a_n,a_{n+1})$ is equivalent to the sequence being arithmetic starting from $n$. See my (partial) answer.

This is not an answer, but is too long for a comment.
First, remember that "if a convex sequence increases once, it increases forever after" (in other words, if $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ is convex and $c_1<c_2$, then $c_2<c_3$ also). It follows that $(\frac{1}{a_n})$ is either eventually increasing or always nonincreasing. The former is impossible because it would entail that the positive integer sequence $(a_n)$ is eventually decreasing. So $(a_n)$ is nondecreasing, $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ for every $n$.
But if $a_n=a_{n+1}=a$ for some $n$, it is straightforward to see that the next terms go $a-1,a-2,\ldots ,3,2,1$, at which point the sequence stalls. So we can assume that $(a_n)$ is increasing,  $a_n \lt a_{n+1}$ for every $n$. In particular $(a_n)$ is unbounded.
Next, we can clarify when a pair of successive terms $(a_n,a_{n+1})$ has the property that the sequence starting at $n$ is an arithmetic sequence. If we put $d=a_{n+1}-a_n$, notice the two identities
$$
a_n+2d+1-\bigg(\frac{a_n(a_n+d)}{a_n-d}\bigg)=a_n-(2d^2+d), \ 
\bigg(\frac{a_n(a_n+d)}{a_n-d}\bigg)-(a_n+2d) = 2d^2
\tag{1}
$$
Combining this with the definition of $a_{n+2}$, we see that
$$
a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}-a_n \ \text{iff} \ a_n \geq 2d^2+d \tag{2} 
$$
Using induction and the fact that $(a_n)$ is increasing, we deduce from (2) that for every $n$,
$(a_k)_{k\geq n}$ is an arithmetic sequence iff
$$
a_n \geq 2(a_{n+1}-a_n)^2+(a_{n+1}-a_n) \tag{3}
$$
So we may assume without loss that the condition (3) is false for every $n$, or in other words
that $D_n=2(a_{n+1}-a_n)^2+(a_{n+1}-a_n)-a_n$ is positive.
Numerical examples suggest that
{\bf Conjecture 1}. If  $D_n \gt 0$, then $D_{n+1} \gt 0$.
My proof for conjecture 1 is still incomplete, but it seems much easier to tackle that the general problem,
given that its statement involves only three integer variables.
If conjecture 1 is true, if the sequence $(a_{n+1}-a_n)$ is eventually constant, then it is in fact
immediately constant, starting from $n=0$.
A conjecture also independently made by @VarunVejalla is
{\bf Conjecture 2}. If $D_0 \gt 0$, then the sequence is finite.
There is also a stronger version of conjecture 2 :
{\bf Conjecture 3}. If $D_0 \gt 0$, then the sequence has length at most $a_0$ (with the exception of the sequence $(2,3,5,14)$ which has length $4$ and $a_0=2$).
What is amazing in the numerical examples is that those sequences are so short and yet often reach rather high values.
An example is $210; 221; 233; 246; 260; 275; 291; 308; 327; 348; 371; 397; 426; 459; 497;
 541; 593; 656; 733; 830; 956; 1127; 1372; 1753; 2426; 3937; 10438$.

I may have a proof sketch that there is no such sequence such that its series converges, but I myself am a bit skeptical of it at the moment.
Consider that we can rewrite this inequality
$\frac{1}{a_{n-1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} > \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}$ in terms of the discrete derivative of $\frac{1}{a_n}$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a_{n}} - \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} < \frac{1}{a_{n + 1}} - \frac{1}{a_{n}} \qquad (*)
\end{align}
But note that taking the discrete antiderivative implies
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{a_{i}} - \frac{1}{a_{i-1}}\right) < \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{a_{i + 1}} - \frac{1}{a_{i}}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{a_{n}} - \frac{1}{a_{0}} < \frac{1}{a_{n + 1}} - \frac{1}{a_{1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{a_{1}} - \frac{1}{a_{0}}  < \frac{1}{a_{n + 1}} - \frac{1}{a_{n}} \qquad (**)$$
Taking discrete antiderivative again
$$(\frac{1}{a_{1}} - \frac{1}{a_{0}})n  < \frac{1}{a_{n + 1}} - \frac{1}{a_{0}} \leq 0$$
$$(\frac{1}{a_{1}} - \frac{1}{a_{0}})n  + \frac{1}{a_{0}} < \frac{1}{a_{n + 1}}  \leq \frac{1}{a_{0}} \qquad  (***)$$
Now, we note that since the LHS is eventually negative, trying to define a sequence which maximizes this inequality $(***)$ will eventually fail. But suppose we have a sequence satisfying $(*)$ where each $a_{n + 1}$ is maximal. Call this $(\alpha_n)$. And assume for contradiction that $\sum^\infty \frac{1}{\alpha_n}$ converges
By taking derivatives of $(***)$ we yield
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a_{n}} - \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} \prec \frac{1}{a_{n + 1}} - \frac{1}{a_{n}} 
\end{align}
(Where $\prec$ means eventually less than). Since we assumed that $\sum^\infty \frac{1}{\alpha_n}$ converges, a convergent sequence satisfying $(***)$ will be asymptotically equivalent to $(\alpha_n)$.
We then create some sequence $(\alpha'_n)$ satisfying $(***)$ such that it is eventually always greater than $(\alpha_n)$.
But since $(\alpha'_n)$ is asymptotically equivalent to $(\alpha_n)$, it will eventually contradict the maximality of $(\alpha_n)$.
Indeed, by their asymptotic equivalence, one should eventually be able to replace $\frac{1}{\alpha_{n + 1}}$ with $\frac{1}{\alpha'_{n + 1}}$ in $(*)$.
Edit I've added some additional detail. In retrospect, this probably should be a comment but it is too long. The problem is I am simply not sure if the final step is valid. It feels likely to work though in the case where we are dealing with non-strict inequality ($\leq$) at the very least, and perhaps the general idea can be of some use.

I didn't get much sleep last night: there could be something wrong about this final deduction, I myself am skeptical of it since I have not formally verified that it works. But don't have much time right now so will come back later and try and make it more rigorous.

Please prioritise sleep. It is more important than gaining 100 points.

@AdamRubinson Lol I appreciate the concern; I did not neglect sleep for the points, but because it is an interesting problem that I could not stop thinking about. I may have answered prematurely, but I figured someone with more experience in asymptotic analysis would be able to quickly tell if this was a useful line of reasoning or not.
